# Run and reference function once in psql

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that returns table of IDs for a complex lookup of nodes.

The queries using this function, require it more than once - is there a way to get and name the function result once - to make the code cleaner:

```
SELECT channels.name
FROM channels
WHERE (
      channels.to_id   IN (SELECT matchingNodes(1,1)) 
  AND channels.from_id IN (SELECT matchingNodes(1,1))
);
```

I am using PostgreSQL 11 and the queries get more complicated (more calls to `matchingNodes`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Assuming the function matchingnodes is defined as `returns table (...)` you can also avoid a second sub-query by selecting the columns of the function twice. Set returning functions should be used in the `FROM` clause to begin with.

So instead of `select matchingnodes(1,1)` use `select id, id from matchingnodes(1,1)` (assuming the column returned by the function is named `id`):

```
with nodes as (
  select id, id
  from matchingnodes(1,1)
) 
select ch.name
from channels ch
where (ch.to_id, ch.from_id) in (select id, id,
                                 from nodes);
```